# Pushing Rails App to Heroku Displays "Application Error" on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I've been trying to push my Rails app to Heroku and continue to receive an application error on the Heroku page (http://mighty-atoll-2395.herokuapp.com).

There's a couple warnings in the command line, but I can't find a work around for either. Any idea on getting the app to display correctly on Heroki?

Here's what I'm seeing in the log file:

```
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-1.9.3
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
-binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
       Using rake (10.1.0)
       Using i18n (0.6.4)
       Using minitest (4.7.5)
       Using multi_json (1.7.7)
       Using atomic (1.1.10)
       Using thread_safe (0.1.0)
       Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Using activesupport (4.0.0)
       Using builder (3.1.4)
       Using erubis (2.7.0)
       Using rack (1.5.2)
       Using rack-test (0.6.2)
       Using actionpack (4.0.0)
       Using mime-types (1.23)
       Using polyglot (0.3.3)
       Using treetop (1.4.14)
       Using mail (2.5.4)
       Using actionmailer (4.0.0)
       Using activemodel (4.0.0)
       Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
       Using arel (4.0.0)
       Using activerecord (4.0.0)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Using execjs (1.4.0)
       Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Using thor (0.18.1)
       Using railties (4.0.0)
       Using coffee-rails (4.0.0)
       Using hike (1.2.3)
       Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Using pg (0.15.1)
       Using tilt (1.4.1)
       Using sprockets (2.10.0)
       Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
       Using rails (4.0.0)
       Using rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
       Using rails_stdout_logging (0.0.1)
       Using rails_12factor (0.0.2)
       Using sass (3.2.9)
       Using sass-rails (4.0.0)
       Using turbolinks (1.3.0)
       Using uglifier (2.1.2)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       Asset precompilation completed (14.56s)
       Cleaning assets
-----> WARNINGS:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types      -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker

-----> Compiled slug size: 19.1MB
-----> Launching... done, v9
       http://mighty-atoll-2395.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:mighty-atoll-2395.git
   fae49e7..432aad3  master -> master

C:\Sites\code\omrails>heroku open
Opening mighty-atoll-2395... done
```

**Here's the gemfile.lock:**

```
    GEM
                  remote: https://rubygems.org/
                  specs:
                    actionmailer (4.0.0)
                      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
                      mail (~> 2.5.3)
                    actionpack (4.0.0)
                      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
                      builder (~> 3.1.0)
                      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
                      rack (~> 1.5.2)
                      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
                    activemodel (4.0.0)
                      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
                      builder (~> 3.1.0)
                    activerecord (4.0.0)
                      activemodel (= 4.0.0)
                      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
                      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
                      arel (~> 4.0.0)
                    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
                    activesupport (4.0.0)
                      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
                      minitest (~> 4.2)
                      multi_json (~> 1.3)
                      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
                      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
                    arel (4.0.0)
                    atomic (1.1.10)
                    builder (3.1.4)
                    coffee-rails (4.0.0)
                      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
                      railties (>= 4.0.0.beta, < 5.0)
                    coffee-script (2.2.0)
                      coffee-script-source
                      execjs
                    coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
                    erubis (2.7.0)
                    execjs (1.4.0)
                      multi_json (~> 1.0)
                    hike (1.2.3)
                    i18n (0.6.4)
                    jquery-rails (3.0.4)
                      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
                      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
                    mail (2.5.4)
                      mime-types (~> 1.16)
                      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
                    mime-types (1.23)
                    minitest (4.7.5)
                    multi_json (1.7.7)
                    pg (0.14.1)
                    pg (0.14.1-x86-mingw32)
                    polyglot (0.3.3)
                    rack (1.5.2)
                    rack-test (0.6.2)
                      rack (>= 1.0)
                    rails (4.0.0)
                      actionmailer (= 4.0.0)
                      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
                      activerecord (= 4.0.0)
                      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
                      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
                      railties (= 4.0.0)
                      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
                    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
                      rails_serve_static_assets
                      rails_stdout_logging
                    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.1)
                    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.1)
                    railties (4.0.0)
                      actionpack (= 4.0.0)
                      activesupport (= 4.0.0)
                      rake (>= 0.8.7)
                      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
                    rake (10.1.0)
                    sass (3.2.9)
                    sass-rails (4.0.0)
                      railties (>= 4.0.0.beta, < 5.0)
                      sass (>= 3.1.10)
                      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0.0)
                    sprockets (2.10.0)
                      hike (~> 1.2)
                      multi_json (~> 1.0)
                      rack (~> 1.0)
                      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
                    sprockets-rails (2.0.0)
                      actionpack (>= 3.0)
                      activesupport (>= 3.0)
                      sprockets (~> 2.8)
                    sqlite3 (1.3.7)
                    sqlite3 (1.3.7-x86-mingw32)
                    thor (0.18.1)
                    thread_safe (0.1.0)
                      atomic
                    tilt (1.4.1)
                    treetop (1.4.14)
                      polyglot
                      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
                    turbolinks (1.3.0)
                      coffee-rails
                    tzinfo (0.3.37)
                    uglifier (2.1.1)
                      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
                      multi_json (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)

                PLATFORMS
                  x86-mingw32

                DEPENDENCIES
                  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
                  jquery-rails
                  pg
                  rails (= 4.0.0)
                  rails_12factor
                  sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
                  sqlite3
                  turbolinks
                  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

And here's the results from running "heroku logs"

```
    C:\Sites\code\omrails>heroku logs
2013-07-16T11:19:33.304014+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T11:19:34.622487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T11:19:34.636847+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T11:19:42.274419+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
iled to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-07-16T11:19:42.274683+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-07-16T11:29:55.137271+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T11:29:58.770480+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 9086 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T11:29:59.660870+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T11:30:01.176475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T11:30:01.160705+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T11:30:09.070042+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
iled to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-07-16T11:30:09.070343+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-07-16T11:39:57.770188+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T11:40:00.540697+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 11757 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T11:40:01.430465+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T11:40:02.750131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T11:40:10.658372+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-07-16T11:40:10.658099+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
iled to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-07-16T11:50:08.142839+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T11:50:10.759025+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 26647 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T11:50:11.348142+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T11:50:12.832729+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T11:50:12.848084+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T12:00:18.471168+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T12:00:20.816512+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 5730 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T12:00:21.380690+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T12:00:22.610042+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T12:00:22.623996+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T12:10:59.938295+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T12:11:03.824973+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 24056 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T12:11:04.606350+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T12:11:06.369088+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T12:11:06.658939+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T12:21:23.512152+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T12:21:27.155611+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 8236 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T12:21:27.848485+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T12:21:29.251969+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T12:21:29.263626+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T12:31:39.793519+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T12:31:42.568819+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 32225 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T12:31:43.195672+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T12:31:44.327341+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T12:42:10.940790+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T12:42:12.287511+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 36313 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T12:42:12.945230+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T12:42:14.194391+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T12:42:14.207900+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T12:52:44.091158+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T12:52:47.174829+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 5362 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T12:52:48.038972+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T12:52:49.762964+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T12:52:49.796772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T12:52:57.496214+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-07-16T12:52:57.495946+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
iled to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-07-16T13:02:53.952245+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T13:02:55.992381+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 8940 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T13:02:56.621037+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T13:02:57.730673+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T13:02:57.747832+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T13:13:26.922885+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T13:13:30.795116+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 40027 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T13:13:31.478702+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T13:13:32.931193+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T13:13:32.948768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T13:13:40.969538+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-07-16T13:13:40.969292+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
iled to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-07-16T13:23:38.291859+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T13:23:48.448293+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 31010 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T13:23:49.137682+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T13:23:50.512893+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T13:23:51.797084+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T13:34:19.027392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T13:34:23.468358+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 31953 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T13:34:24.522090+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T13:34:26.512507+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T13:34:33.959755+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
iled to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-07-16T13:34:33.960327+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-07-16T13:34:26.525160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T13:44:53.787843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 24221 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T13:44:55.048133+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T13:44:56.556845+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T13:44:56.570675+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T13:55:26.168843+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T13:55:31.004823+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 12522 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T13:55:32.837429+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T13:55:34.258581+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T13:55:34.268191+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T14:06:05.329757+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T14:06:09.677300+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 11727 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T14:06:10.610521+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T14:06:12.161225+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T14:06:12.152121+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T14:06:19.935244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
iled to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-07-16T14:06:19.935530+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-07-16T14:16:45.386745+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-07-16T14:16:48.777292+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 57386 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-16T14:16:49.627436+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-07-16T14:16:51.106043+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-16T14:16:51.122977+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-07-16T14:16:59.052342+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-07-16T14:16:59.052103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
iled to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
```

Comment: You probably need to run your database migrations on heroku, check error messages on heroku, run: heroku logs

Comment: can we see your gemfile lock? Sounds like you have windows specific gems.  You could try removing those, or bundling on a linux system and committing that lock.  Best of luck!

Comment: Just added the gemfile.lock and below that is the results from "heroku logs"

Comment: `app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory` - that seems like a windows specific version of ruby  - what is in your actual Gemfile ? I think it is trying to tell heroku to load ruby.exe which does not exist (on linux it would just be ruby)